# Perl Update array

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I am getting data back from a database query but I need to update an array.

```
sub get_query_data{
   my ($self, $user_id) = @_;

   my $sql_query = "Select * from table";
   my ( $returndata ) = $self->_exec_and_fetch_all( $sql );

   for ( @$returndata ) {
       push( @$_, 'replace me' );
   }

   return $returndata;
}
```

How do I replace the third element when I am looping through the data?
There is data coming back from the query but he above is not working.

Comment: Please, post the actual code. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That is it.  I run a select statement and data gets returned to returndata array.  But I need to replace the 3rd element from each row.  I don't know what else you need?

Comment: `@$_[2] = 'replace me';` will replace the 3rd element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar: It will, but it's much better as `$_->[2] = 'replace me'` or even `${$_}[2] = 'replace me`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$self->_exec_and_fetch_all` can return `undef`,

```
my $rows = $self->_exec_and_fetch_all($sql);
if ($rows) {
   for my $row (@$rows) {
      $row->[2] = 'replaceme';
   }
}

return $rows;
```

Otherwise,

```
my $rows = $self->_exec_and_fetch_all($sql);
for my $row (@$rows) {
   $row->[2] = 'replaceme';
}

return $rows;
```

or

```
my $rows = $self->_exec_and_fetch_all($sql);
$_->[2] = 'replaceme' for @$rows;
return $rows;
```